# Action not being passed to the reducer - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with my react/redux app, a specific action `buildModalForm()` is not being passed from `actions/index/` to the reducer. I am fairly new to react so not sure what the problem is.

In container/buidpage:

```
    class BuildPage extends Component {

   componentWillMount(){
     this.props.fetchAPIJobs();
     this.props.buildModalForm();
   }

//....


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
      rowData  : state.buildJobs.rowData,
      columns  : state.buildJobs.columns,
      reactView: state.reactView
      }
 }


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onFormClick: () => {
            dispatch( showModal() )
        },
        onModalClose: () => {
            dispatch( hideModal() )
        },
        buildModalForm : () => {
          dispatch( buildModalForm() )
        },
        fetchAPIJobs : () => {
          fetchAPIJobs(fetchAPIJobs())
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BuildPage)
```

In actions/index:

```
    import * as actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes'

export function buildModalForm(){
  console.log("in action creator buildModalForm");
  return { type: actionTypes.BUILD_MODAL_FORM }
}
```

in constants/actionTypes:

`export const BUILD_MODAL_FORM         = 'BUILD_MODAL_FORM'`

in reducers/reactView: (connected in to the root reducer)

```
 import {
  HIDE_MODAL,
  SHOW_MODAL,
  BUILD_MODAL_FORM
} from '../constants/actionTypes.js'

import {
  BUILD_INITIAL_STATE,
  ROOT_INITIAL_STATE
} from '../constants/initialStates'


export default function reactView(state = {}, action) {
  console.log("in react view reducer :", action.type);
  switch (action.type){
    case SHOW_MODAL :
      return Object.assign( {}, state, {modalDisplay: true})
    case HIDE_MODAL :
      return Object.assign( {}, state, {modalDisplay: false})
    case BUILD_MODAL_FORM :
      return Object.assign( {}, state, BUILD_INITIAL_STATE)
    default :
      return state
  }
}
```

The `console.log` in actions/index is logging that its inside the action, and the logs inside the reducer are reading the other action types, but `BUILD_MODAL_FORM` is not passing being logged. Any help my appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other reducers ? Are you sure they don't mutate the state ?

Comment: @VonD Yes I have some other reducers, but the all use Object.assign, similar to shown here. I was under the impression that Object.assign doesnt mutate state, but  perhaps that is not right?

Comment: it depends `Object.assign({}, state, newData)`, as you do here, doesn't. But `Object.assign(state, newData)` would.

Comment: ahh yeah I have always given the first argument as an empty object. That's useful to know for the future though.

Comment: Actually silly mistake there was a typo in the middleware. Ill close this.

Answer (score 0):

-- I made a typo and didn't return anything from the middleware. Case closed, doh.